# Autocad 2015 plugin autoload

Tags: c#, .net, autocad-plugin

I whant to load my plugin on autcad startup and this is the PackageContents.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationPackage SchemaVersion="1.0" 
                    AutodeskProduct="AutoCAD" Name="AutoCADMyPlugin" 
                    Description="AutoCADMyPlugin" Version="1.0.0" Version="1.0.0" 
                    ProductType="Application" SupportedLocales="Enu" AppNameSpace="AutoCADMyPlugin" Author="Autodesk, Inc." 
                    ProductCode="{B2D833E7-8E89-45FF-9281-B8CE38F3BF8C}" UpgradeCode="{34060BF2-49ED-46A2-BF6E-4C7B1772B397}" 
                                        OnlineDocumentation="www.autodesk.com">

  <CompanyDetails Name="Autodesk, Inc." Url="www.autodesk.com" Email="info@autodesk.com" />
  <RuntimeRequirements OS="Win32|Win64" Platform="AutoCAD*" SeriesMin="R19.1" SeriesMax="R20.0" />

  <Components>
    <RuntimeRequirements OS="Win32|Win64" Platform="AutoCAD*" SeriesMin="R19.1" SeriesMax="R20.0" />
    <ComponentEntry 
                AppName="AutoCADMyPlugin" 
                ModuleName=".\Contents\AutoCADMyPlugin.dll" 
                AppDescription="AutoCAD 2015 my Plugin" 
                LoadOnAutoCADStartup="True" >
</ComponentEntry>
```

Dll works fine when I use NETLOAD command, my ribbon menus appears, but on autocad sturtup it doesn't work...

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the bundle folder into the autoload, %APPDATA%/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins, directory.
Also [this](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html) white paper illustrates the entire process.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong symbols, ModuleName should look like this:

ModuleName="./Contents/AutoCADMyPlugin.dll"